# Scala: Splitting a list into sublist

Tags: scala

Can anyone explain: How to split a list in sublists where:

List:

```
scala> val ls = List("P ", "PP ", "PP ", "PP ", "P ", "PP ", "PP ", "P ")
```

Or

```
scala> val ls = List("P", "PP", "PP", "PP", "P", "PP", "PP", "P")
```

Sublists:

```
List("P", "PP", "PP", "PP"), List("P", "PP", "PP"), List("P")
```

**EDITED**:: What I really want is to split the list at every occurrence of a particular string!

TIA.

Comment: What the logic here? Split when the length decreases?

Comment: You need to encode list. There is a logic. After change length to one all items in one list and so on.

Comment: Did you try check if there is something here ?? you can use : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html  look at takeWhile, partiion, slice methods.

Comment: @Marth I have explained the requirement in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `foldLeft`:

```
l.foldLeft(List[List[String]]()) {
  case (Nil, s) => List(List(s))
  case (result, "P ") => result :+ List("P ")
  case (result, s) => result.dropRight(1) :+ (result.last :+ s)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive (but not tail-recursive) solution:

```
val l = List("P ", "PP ", "PP ", "PP ", "P ", "PP ", "PP ", "P ")

def splitBy(l: List[String], s: String): List[List[String]] = {
  l.splitAt(l.lastIndexOf(s)) match {
    case (Nil, tail) => List(tail)
    case (head, tail) => splitBy(head, s) :+ tail
  }
}

splitBy(l, "P ") // List(List(P , PP , PP , PP ), List(P , PP , PP ), List(P ))
```

Tail Recursive version:

```
val l = List("P", "PP", "PP", "PP", "P", "PP", "PP", "P")

def splitBy(result: List[List[String]], l: List[String], s: String): List[List[String]] = {
  l.splitAt(l.lastIndexOf(s)) match {
    case (Nil, y) => List(y) ::: result
    case (x, y)   => splitBy(List(y) ::: result, x, s)
  }
}

println(splitBy(Nil, l, "P"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List("P ", "PP ", "PP ", "PP ", "P ", "PP ", "PP ", "P ")
  .scanLeft((0, Option.empty[String])) {
    case ((count, _), "P ") ⇒ (count + 1, Some("P "))
    case ((count, _), s) ⇒ (count, Some(s))
  }.groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.collect { case (cnt, Some(x)) ⇒ x })
  .toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```